# How to add disabled column in datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I tried to add the change password column in the datatables. The logic that is made is, if user status = not active, the change password button is disabled. but the problem occurs, the change password button is disabled only in the first line.

is there a solution to this problem? thank you

The following code to add a column in datatables:

```
{ "render": function(data, type, row){
                if(row.status == 1) {
                    $('#pass').on('mouseover', function(){
                        $('#pass').addClass("enabled");
                    });
                }
                if(row.status == 0) {
                    $('#pass').on('mouseover', function(){
                        $('#pass').addClass("disabled");
                    });
                }

               action = '<button class="btn btn-info" id="pass">change pass</button> ';

                return action;
            }},
```

[The following is a picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VapJf.png)

Comment: You are using the same `id` value for each button, which is not allowed in HTML and so `$('#pass')` will only return the first element on the page with that `id` value.

Comment: then is there a solution to the problem?

Comment: You will need to figure out a way to give each button a unique id (e.g. `#pass1` etc) and then modify the code to set only the relevant button. Without seeing all your code it's hard to know how to do that. I suggest you give it a try and if you still have problems, ask a new question.